# Pagination in Microservice of Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, microservices

I have two microservices which are returning paginated results(Says page size is 10 for both the microservices). I want to create a third microservice which will merge the results of the previous 2 microservices. But the problem is I want my third microservice also to be paginated(Here also I want the page size as 10). How to apply pagination and merge results.

I am able to get the paginated result from my two microservice and also able to merge it. But Not able to apply pagination on the merged results correctly.

Below is the code sample:

```
class Microservice1{
   public List<Item> getItems(Pagination pagination){}
}

class Microservice2{
   public List<Item> getItems(Pagination pagination){}
}


class MainMicroservice{
   private Microservice1 microservice1;
   private Microservice2 microservice2;

   public List<Item> getItem(Pagination pagination){
      List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.addAll(microservice1.getItems(pagination));
      list.addAll(microservice2.getItems(pagination));

      return list;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share what you tried? also can you confirm if you want the page size =10 on the third microservice then are you querying the first and second service to fetch 5 records each? how do you merge the responses?

Comment: @gtiwari333 I have added the code sample.

Comment: If I will keep the page size as 5 for service 1 and 2 than what if there is 4 data in service 1 and 20 data in service 2?

Comment: That depends on your business requirement.

Comment: `what if there is 4 data in service 1 and 20 data in service 2`  I noticed you are using `List` not `Page` so there's no way to see the total records. If you return `Page` then you can check the total size and try to refetch the one more item from service 2 to make the total 10

Comment: Also FYI, Spring provies Pageable object and method argument resolvers to resolve the value based on request. So, you don't need to use your custom `Pagination` object and provide your custom logic to resolve it

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea. 1) You're decreasing performance. 2) You're creating tight dependencies between your services. What if change data contract of service 1? You will have to test and redeploy main service entirely. Also what if service 1 or service 2 is down? Main service will not be able to perform the request. If you want to merge data coming from multiple services you should listen to events and build a projection. This way of thinking will save you more than just pagination problems.